# Build PHP image with gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: php, docker, gitlab, composer-php, gitlab-ci

I would like to build a Docker image when I push code to gitlab.com.

This works fine, up to a point...

**gitlab-ci.yml (1)**

```
image: php:7.4

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/

before_script:
  - echo "Prep me"
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends zip unzip gnupg2
  - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
  - php composer-setup.php
  - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
  - curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
  - echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

build:
  script:
    - echo "Build me"
    - composer install
    - yarn install
```

But nothing gets added into the Gitlab registry. So I've tried adding this to build but docker is not a recognized command.

**gitlab-ci.yml (2)**

```
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

I would have thought it should be simple to get a PHP docker image spun up in no time but it seems to be difficult - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: How is this related to PHP or Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the base image of your GitLab CI right now is `php:7.4`, which does not have the docker commands.

In order to achieve running docker command you will need to use an image like

```
image: docker:19.03.8
```

- See GitLab documentation for reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html
- Also worth a look: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#container-registry-examples-with-gitlab-cicd

Comment: I've tried that and I get 'apt-get' command is unrecognised. :(

Comment: Yes because apt-get is not in the `docker:19.03.9`. 
You are confusing here the image you want to build and put in your registry and the image that GitLab CI is using in order to give you a flexible place to build whatever you want. You composer and the like instructions should be in a DockerFile, not in the pipeline of GitLab itself

Comment: By the way, `apt-get` is erroring because  `docker:19.03.9` is build on top of an Alpine distro, see https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/master/19.03/Dockerfile